# regex to verify comma separated string

Tags: c#, regex

I've got a string in the following format:
name,artist,detail,genre,length

any character can be entered between the commas.
i've made this so far but it doesn't seem to work:

```
if(!Regex.IsMatch(songDetails,@"^([\w]+,)+[\w]+$"))
{
 throw new Exception("Enter data into all cells");
}
```

songDetails is the string input the user enters which I want to verify.

where am I going wrong with this?

edit:
I should be more specific on where this string is coming from.
I'm reading values from a dataGridView. If the user leaves the row blank but enters a value in length, the data is saved, but it shouldn't allow it

Comment: *"any character can be entered between the commas"* - even a comma?

Comment: Also: what is the logic you are trying to implement with the Regex? What is not working?

Comment: I'm trying to check if user has entered data into all the cells of a datagridview.  the problem i have is that if the user enters something in length, the data will be saved. This should not happen.

Comment: I was asking because your Regex checks neither for a minimum number of commas, nor for a max total length. Anyway, use Romoku's solution; it's the best approach

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would probably be simpler to check the length of the split results than to use the regex.

```
var songDetailsArray = songDetails.Split(",");

if(songDetailsArray.Length != 5)
{
     throw new Exception("Enter data into all cells");
}
```

Comment: As the famous quote goes... _Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems._

Comment: thanks!
I guess regex is good for only some things of validating strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the brackets:

```
if(!Regex.IsMatch(songDetails,@"^(\w+,)+\w+$"))
{
  throw new Exception("Enter data into all cells");
}
```

\w is already a character class. If whitespace is allowed too, try this:

```
if(!Regex.IsMatch(songDetails,@"^((\w|\s)+,)+(\w|\s)+$"))
{
  throw new Exception("Enter data into all cells");
}
```